# Predicate method syntax

Tags: ruby, memoization, predicates

I made a class with these methods:

```
def promotion_available?
  promotion.present?
end

def promotion
  @promotion ||= PromotionUser.user(@user.id).available.first
end
```

Then, a colleague removed the `promotion` method, and changed the predicate `promotion_available?` in this way:

```
def promotion_available?
  @promotion ||= PromotionUser.user(@user.id).available.first
end
```

- Can I set an instance variable directly on a predicate method?
- Can a predicate method return an entire object instead of `true`/`false` (I think no, but my colleague says the opposite)?

Comment: @sawa: [sic]? No, it's not sic, it's obviously a typo :)

Answer (score 3):

> Can I set an instance variable directly on a predicate method?

Yes, there's nothing wrong with it. I do it often.

> Can a predicate method return an entire object instead of tre/false (I think no, but my colleague says the opposite)

Yes, this is also common. But it only works if you use idiomatic ruby truthiness checks.

```
if obj.promotion_available? # GOOD
if obj.promotion_available? == true # BAD!
```

Remember, that only `nil` and `false` in ruby are falsey values. Everything else is true. This is why returning an object or nil works kinda like returning true or false.

Comment: The question is not clear at which level it is asking: Whether it is about syntactic correctness or about the convention. Your answer kind of inherits that ambiguity. But, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Although the change "works", it introduces a side effect: you have to call `promotion_available?` before you can actually use the `promotion` (assuming that there is a `promotion` method):

```
your_object.promotion             #=> nil

your_object.promotion_available?
your_object.promotion             #=> <#PromotionUser ...>
```

You original code doesn't have this dependency.

IMO it would be more intuitive to keep the `promotion` method and to remove `promotion_available?`. You could just write:

```
if obj.promotion
  # with promotion
else
  # without promotion
end
```

Comment: `promotion` method was removed, so he probably doesn't need to use it. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev unless it's defined implicitly, e.g. via `attr_accessor`

Comment: Yes, #promotion no longer exists, instead of it we calling @promotion defined on #promotion_available?

Comment: @mirco if you are using `@promotion` somewhere else, you have to remember calling `promotion_available?` beforehand.

Comment: just like that, and I do not think that having to call first #promotion_available? to arrange the instance @promotion is very intuitive and readable

Comment: @mirco exactly, I would keep the `promotion` method instead, see my edit